# Ionic Framework unable to change content src from index.html to index.php

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic Framework.

So via ionic cli i started a new app with blank template to run in android platform.

What i wanted to do is to replace the index.html with index.php in my app's folder that ionic cli automatically created for me.

So i moved into the www folder of my app i deleted the index.html file and instead i created an index.php file, then i moved into config.xml file and i changed the content src to points in the index.php file instead of index.html.

The problem is that i get this error in the browser:

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\cmsApp\www\index.html'**

and seems that my app still points to the default index.html (*that doesn't exists anymore*) instead the php one that i replaced with.

How can i fix that?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify the config file located here :

> /PathOfYourProject/Config.xml

There is a part where you can change the source :

`<content src="index.html"/>`

But i'm not sure that you can place PHP file here.

Comment: Yes i did it and i changed it. I searched and you're able to use php with ionic